# angular route not working properly . first page show other page not switch the view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

angularjs route not working properly . first page show other page not switch the view . here is the code

**script.js**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
    templateUrl: "home.html",
  })
    .when("/About", {
    templateUrl: "About.html",
  })
    .when("/contact", {
    templateUrl: "contact.html",
  });
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Welcome Home</title>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <p><a href="#">Main</a></p>
  <a href="#About">About</a>
  <a href="#contact">contact</a>

  <h3> welcome to the page</h3>

  <div ng-view></div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**home.html**

```
<h1>Welcome Home </h1>
```

**About.html**

```
<h1>Welcome About </h1>
```

**contact.html**

```
<h1>Welcome Contact </h1>
```

Comment: Is there any bug on console?

Comment: add $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); and don't use href="#about", remove # from href.

Comment: just add #! in front of  href it will work like " <a href="#!About">About</a>"

Answer (score 0):

Also be careful about dependency injection.

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
    templateUrl: "home.html",
  })
    .when("/About", {
    templateUrl: "About.html",
  })
    .when("/contact", {
    templateUrl: "contact.html",
  });
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```